# Graphics3D plot Polygon (Joined Table) gets different results with and without decimal point

Tags: graphics, polygons

1. Without decimal point

   ```
    Graphics3D[{Arrowheads[0.03], Black, Specularity[White, 50],
     Polygon[Join[
     Table[{0, 0, 0} + {Cos[a], Sin[a], 0}, {a, 0, π, π/6}],
     Table[{-.5 , 0, 0} + .5 {Cos[a], Sin[a], 0}, {a,
     0, π, π/6}],
     Table[{.5, 0, 0} + .5 {Cos[a], Sin[a], 0}, {a, π,
     2 π, π/6}],
     Table[{0.5, 0, 0} + 0.25 {Cos[a], Sin[a], 0}, {a, 0,
     2 π, π/6}]]]}]
   ```

   [image]
2. With decimal point

   ```
   Graphics3D[{Arrowheads[0.03], Black, Specularity[White, 50],
       Polygon[Join[
     Table[{0, 0, 0} + {Cos[a], Sin[a], 0}, {a, 0, π, π/6}],
     Table[{-.5 , 0, 0} + .5 {Cos[a], Sin[a], 0}, {a,
     0., π, π/6}],
     Table[{.5, 0, 0} + .5 {Cos[a], Sin[a], 0}, {a, π,
     2 π, π/6}],
     Table[{0.5, 0, 0} + 0.25 {Cos[a], Sin[a], 0}, {a, 0.,
     2 π, π/6}]]]}]
   ```

   [image]

Comment: This is because `0.` is a floating point, and `0` an integer. It is best where possible to use integer, or at least rational numbers.

Comment: But I am still not clear about how this difference happens.

Comment: sometimes 0. Will be 0.00~1 or so thus leave out one point in Table, but even this cannot explain this phenomenon. I'm currently without my computer, I will check this out. :) it seems like a mathematica's misbehaviour

Answer (score 1):

- To clarify the problem, we can do the 2D cases at first. We can find that whatever we set the decimal point or not, the joined line is always existence. Althought when we use `Graphics3D` to draw the 3D polygon, the joined line may disappear.

```
poly2d = 
 Polygon[Join[
   Table[{0, 0} + {Cos[a], Sin[a]}, {a, 0, π, π/6}], 
   Table[{-.5, 0} + .5   {Cos[a], Sin[a]}, {a, 0, π, π/6}], 
   Table[{.5, 0} + .5   {Cos[a], Sin[a]}, {a, π, 
     2   π, π/6}], 
   Table[{0.5, 0} + 0.25   {Cos[a], Sin[a]}, {a, 0, 
     2   π, π/6}]]]
Graphics[{FaceForm[Black], EdgeForm[Red], poly2d}]
```

[image]

- In the new version ($Version >12 ) we can seperate the groups of lines into two groups and use the syntax as below to get a hole, althoght we still set the decimal point `{a, 0., π, π/6}` etc..

[image]

```
line1 = Join[
   Table[{0, 0, 0} + {Cos[a], Sin[a], 0}, {a, 0, π, π/6}], 
   Table[{-.5, 0, 0} + .5  {Cos[a], Sin[a], 0}, {a, 
     0., π, π/6}], 
   Table[{.5, 0, 0} + .5  {Cos[a], Sin[a], 0}, {a, π, 
     2  π, π/6}]];
line2 = Table[{0.5, 0, 0} + 0.25  {Cos[a], Sin[a], 0}, {a, 0., 
    2  π, π/6}];
poly = Polygon[line1 -> line2]
Graphics3D[poly]
```

[image]